# remembering selected checkboxes that come from a database

Tags: php, database, forms, session, checkbox

I am making a form and one of the inputs are a number of checkboxes that come from a database. If the form isn't filled out correctly, the user should be returned to the form but with the selected checkboxes should still be checked once a user returns.

The page containing the form uses an `if`, if the user made a mistake, he/she receives a form that contains sessions so the stuff that was filled in is still there. The other form doesn't have sessions.

This is the code I use to read out the checkbox options from the database:

```
$STH = $DBH -> prepare("SELECT * FROM tbloptions");

    $STH -> execute();

    $STH -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    while($row = $STH -> fetch())
    {
        $optionID = $row -> optionID;
        $option = $row -> option;


        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $option ?>" value="<?php echo $optionid ?>"> <?php echo $option ?><br>
    <?php
    }

    ?>
```

what code should I use for the form with the sessions and what code should I use to create the sessions

thanks

Comment: You have to set the HTML "checked" attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Adding square braces to the checkbox name creates an array of the selected values in the group

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value="<?php echo $optionid ?>" /><?php echo $option ?><br />
```

This can be retrieved in PHP with a simple loop:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['chk_group'])) {
    $optionArray = $_POST['chk_group'];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($optionArray); $i++) {
        echo $optionArray[$i]."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Next, you can redisplay the form with the "checked" arg if the option is in the $optionArray array

Answer (score 0):

This depends how you process your form variables. The following assumes no processing and that the data is POSTed.

Determine if the value of checkbox "name" is set to "value" and if so, check it:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $option ?>" value="<?php echo $optionid ?>" <?php if($_POST[$option]==$optionid){echo' checked="checked"';} ?>> <?php echo $option ?>
...
```